# NETGEAR Wifi drops sometimes randomly

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router

Not sure if this is the correct Stack Exchange site to ask this question but it was the closest I could find.

I have a NETGEAR b90-755025-15 router with AT&T service, and I have download speed at about 7MB, and 1MB Upload speed. For some strange reason, my Wifi keeps dropping. Sometimes the Wifi will work completely fine with zero problems and 3 people will be using the Wifi, other times it drops and is really slow. Sometimes no one will be using the Wifi except me, and it drops and slows down a lot.

I am not sure what the problem could be. Is there a way to see what the error is, like checking some sort of logs, maybe any ideas why this could be happening? Today my Wifi worked all morning and part of the afternoon and now its 12 AM and its been really slow for the past 5 hours.

I don't know much about networking, so was hoping someone could help.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There's a few things I'd do/consider.

1. Wireless contention/physical layout. I'd suggest grabbing a smartphone and a wifi analyser app - [I've used the free version of inssider](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.metageek). Make sure that you're on the channel with the least overlap possible.
2. Router might just be suffering under load. I'd also check with a wired connection to make sure its just wireless.

Comment: Is it possible that having bluetooth activated on a laptop using the internet can affect the internet speed. I just turned off bluetooth on a laptop in the house using internet and it seemed to make the internet faster.

Comment: They use different bands IIRC so... this shouldn't happen